# Is it possible to have 3 Wordpress websites(copies) with each a different language?

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

i'm working on a website in Wordpress that needs to be in several different languages. 
I tried alot of options and several plugins(including WMPL) but to no avail.

So i was thinking, kind of as a last resort, is it a good idea(and is it possible?) to install multiple Wordpress installations on 1 server each in its own folder (/en, /de, /nl, etc.) and have each site in it's own language with links to the other languages/wordpress installations?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to post this @ http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was going wrong for you with the WPML multilingual plugin?

There is a lot you can tweak and there are some neat ways of making other plugins and functionality work nicely with it.

If you haven't already committed to another solution and want to post your WPML issues I'd be happy to help (as far as I can ;-))

Answer (score 2):

Why don't go with a Multiple User installation, supported since 3.0? All sites use the same installation, plug-ins and themes and you can set each blog to it's own language!

http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WPMU

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it a good idea, would e very hard to maintain IMHO!

I would suggest trying all available plugins before, have you tried this:

- [xLanguage](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xlanguage/)
- [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into some automated google-translation:

[more .htaccess tips and tricks..](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php) suggests the following:

> **automatic translation** 
>   If you don't
>   read English, or some of your guests
>   don't, here's a neat way to have the
>   wonderful Google translator provide
>   automatic on-the-fly translation for
>   your site's pages. Something like
>   this..
>
> they simply add their country code to the end of the link, or you  do..

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)-fr$ http://www.google.com/translate_c?hl=fr&sl=en&u=http://corz.org/$1 [R,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-de$ http://www.google.com/translate_c?hl=de&sl=en&u=http://corz.org/$1 [R,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-es$ http://www.google.com/translate_c?hl=es&sl=en&u=http://corz.org/$1 [R,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-it$ http://www.google.com/translate_c?hl=it&sl=en&u=http://corz.org/$1 [R,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pt$ http://www.google.com/translate_c?hl=pt&sl=en&u=http://corz.org/$1 [R,NC]
```

> You can create your menu with its
>   flags or whatever you like, and add
>   the country code to end of the links..
>
> Although it is very handy, and I've
>   been using it here for a couple of
>   years here at the org, for my
>   international blog readers, all two of
>   them, heh. Almost no one knows about
>   it, mainly because I don't have any
>   links . One day I'll probably do a wee
>   toolbar with flags and what-not.
>   Perhaps not. Trouble is, the Google
>   translator stops translating after a
>   certain amount of characters (which
>   seems to be increasing, good), though
>   these same rules could easily be
>   applied to other translators, and if
>   you find a good one, one that will
>   translate a really huge  document
>   on-the-fly, do let me know!
>
> If you wanted to be really clever, you
>   could even perform some some kind of
>   IP block check and present the correct
>   version automatically, but that is
>   outside the scope of this document.
>   note: this may be undesirable for
>   pages where technical commands are
>   given (like this page) because the
>   commands will also be translated.
>   "RewriteEngine dessus" will almost
>   certainly get you a 500 error page!
>
> Another thing you might like to try;
>   rather than individual country flags;
>   fr, de, etc., use the "u" flag, for
>   "Universal". In theory, Google will
>   check the client's location, and
>   automatically translate to that
>   language. One line in your .htaccess
>   would cover all languages, and
>   automatically cover new ones as Google
>   adds them.